# Reverse sort and argsort in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, information-retrieval, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to write a function in Python (still a noob!) which returns indices and scores of documents ordered by the inner products of their tfidf scores. The procedure is:

- Compute vector of inner products between doc `idx` and all other documents
- Sort in descending order
- Return the "scores" and indices from the second one to the end (i.e. not itself)

The code I have at the moment is:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

def get_related(tfidf, idx) :
    ''' return the top documents '''

    # calculate inner product   
    v = np.inner(tfidf, tfidf[idx].transpose())

    # sort
    vs = np.sort(v.toarray(), axis=0)[::-1]
    scores = vs[1:,]

    # sort indices
    vi = np.argsort(v.toarray(), axis=0)[::-1]
    idxs = vi[1:,] 

    return (scores, idxs)
```

where `tfidf` is a `sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'`.

This seems inefficient, as the sort is performed twice (`sort()` then `argsort()`), and the results have to then be reversed.

- Can this be done more efficiently?
- Can this be done without converting the sparse matrix using `toarray()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there's any real need to skip the `toarray`. The `v` array will be only `n_docs` long, which is dwarfed by the size of the `n_docs` × `n_terms` tf-idf matrix in practical situations. Also, it will be quite dense since any term shared by two documents will give them a non-zero similarity. Sparse matrix representations only pay off when the matrix you're storing is *very* sparse (I've seen >80% figures for Matlab and assume that Scipy will be similar, though I don't have an exact figure).

The double sort can be skipped by doing

```
v = v.toarray()
vi = np.argsort(v, axis=0)[::-1]
vs = v[vi]
```

Btw., your use of `np.inner` on sparse matrices is not going to work with the latest versions of NumPy; the safe way of taking an inner product of two sparse matrices is

```
v = (tfidf * tfidf[idx, :]).transpose()
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. Just wondering, do you know how the  `toarray()` function works - I take it that it doesn't make a copy of the data

Comment: @tdc: it does make a copy. And it fills in the zero positions.

Comment: @tdc: I just realised that there's one more important optimization to make: you should be using CSR sparse matrices. In any other representation, the inner product computation will be suboptimal.

Comment: 1) can I do things like sorting without making a copy? 2) how expensive is the translation from csc to csr?

Comment: 1) Not that I know. 2) Very cheap. I believe it's just a matter of rearranging some indices, without the data being actually copied.

Comment: There is a parentheses error in the final line of this and I can't tell what your mean. Does the transpose apply to the indexed inner array, or to the result after multiplying them? Is the last closing parentheses on the right just a typo, or not?